# Delete functionality not working for MySQL table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js

My delete button isn't working to delete entries out of my table. Any ideas why? The delete script is displaying on my network tab, but when I click the Delete button, it just redirects me to the page.

Here is my get route to display the page

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    var callbackCount = 0;
    var context = {};
    context.jsscripts = ["deletepokemon.js"];
    var mysql = req.app.get('mysql');
    getPokemon(res, mysql, context, complete);
    getMoves(res, mysql, context, complete);
    function complete() {
        callbackCount++;
        if(callbackCount >= 2){
            res.render('pokemon', context);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my delete route

```
router.delete('/:id', function(req, res) {
    var mysql = req.app.get('mysql');
    var sql = "DELETE FROM pokemon WHERE id=?";
    var inserts = [req.params.id];
    sql = mysql.pool.query(sql, inserts, function(error, results, fields){
            if(error){
             res.write(JSON.stringify(error));
             res.status(400);
             res.end();
            } else{
                    res.status(202).end();
            }
        })
    })
```

Here is my delete script with jQuery

```
function deletePokemon(id){
        $.ajax({
                url: '/pokemon/' + id,
                type: 'DELETE',
                success: function(result){
                  window.location.reload(true);
        }
     })
};
```

Here is my handlebars file to render it all

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <th>Pokemon Name   </th>
        <th>Evolution Level   </th>
        <th>Move Name   </th>
    </thead>
   <input type="text" class="search form-control" id="searchinput" placeholder="Pokemon Name">
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" onclick="getUsers({{searchinput}})">
        <br>
    <tbody>
        {{#each pokemon}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{pokemonname}}</td>
            <td>{{evolutionlevel}}</td>
            <td>{{movename}}</td>
            <td><button onclick="deletePokemon({{id}})">Delete</button></td>
        <td><a href="/pokemon/{{id}}">Update</a></td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
    <form id="addpokemon" action="/pokemon" method="POST">
       Pokemon Name: <input type="text" name="pokemonname"><br>
       Evolution Level: <input type="text" name="evolutionlevel"><br>
       Move Name: <select name="movename">
        {{#each move}}
        <option value="{{id}}">{{primarymovename}}</option>
        {{/each}}
        </select><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `/pokemon` your root url? If not, in your ajax call, your url is `url: '/pokemon/' + id` but in your node router you are expecting '/id'. It should be

```
router.delete('/pokemon/:id', function(req, res) {
   ....
}
```